# Can I make a div behave like a separate viewport

Tags: javascript, css

Let's say I have a page with 2 divs. Each div contains the same data, say `content x`.

`content x` is responsive, with media query and viewport.

`Div1` is as big as the page `width: 100%`

`Div2` has `width: 320px;`

What I want to achieve is that when I am on desktop, I like `div2` to show the contents as if it was a mobile phone (simulate the mobile phone viewport) and `div1` stay the same (desktop version).

Is this possible, without modifying CSS of `content x` ?

The reason I want to do this is because `content x` has a lot of stuff and would take time to add css.

When I set 'div2 width: 320px`,`content x` is not rearranged properly (as it would on a mobile screen).

Comment: Your best bet may be iframes -- To my knowledge, media queries and other determinations for mobile responsive work off of the window's dimensions, not the DIV's (although there is rumor of something like that down the road in CSS -- just not here today)

Comment: Your really best bet is to use the tools browsers have already build-in these days for such purposes. Trying to emulate it inside a “bigger” page is bound to fail in one regard or the other, sooner or later. (For example device-width based queries would probably fail immediately, if you just used a div to “simulate” a small viewport.)

Comment: I think iframe is the only solution to this.

Comment: iframe or object will work